# Jest throwing is not a functon error when parent class is mocked and child class method is called

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have RabbitMqClient which i use as short term storage.

```
import { environment } from '@Utils/environment'
import { AMQPChannel, AMQPClient } from '@cloudamqp/amqp-client'
import { AMQPBaseClient } from '@cloudamqp/amqp-client/types/amqp-base-client'

export class RabbitMqService extends AMQPClient {
  public connection?: AMQPBaseClient
  private lastDispatch: number = Date.now()

  public constructor() {
    super(environment.rabbitMqUrl)
    this.connection = undefined
  }

  public async connectToInstance(): Promise<AMQPBaseClient> {
    this.connection = await this.connect()
    return this.connection
  }
}
```

I tried testing it with jest by mockin parent class `AMQPClient` ...

```
import { RabbitMqService } from '../rabbit-mq.service'

jest.mock('@cloudamqp/amqp-client', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@cloudamqp/amqp-client'),
    AMQPClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        connect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
      }
    })
  }
});

it('Should ...', async () => {
  // Given
  const rabbitMqService = new RabbitMqService();
  // When
  await rabbitMqService.connectToInstance()
})
```

But this results in this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEOJi.png)

This is my jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types'

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  automock: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^Root/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src',
    '^@Assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^@Data/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/data/$1',
    '^@Events/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/events/$1',
    '^@Guards/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/guards/$1',
    '^@Interceptors/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/interceptors/$1',
    '^@Services/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/services/$1',
    '^@Types/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/types/$1',
    '^@Utils/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils/$1'
  }
}
export default config
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test code is hard to use code

Instead of extending a class, why don't you use Dependency Injection code?

A dependency (like `AMQPClient`):

```js
export class DIClass {
  public connect(): string {
    return "http://connection.url.com";
  }
}
```

A class that uses a dependency (like `RabbitMqService`):

```js
export class TestingClass {
  public connection?: string;

  constructor(private readonly injectedDependency: DIClass) {}

  public connect() {
    this.connection = this.injectedDependency.connect();
  }
}
```

The tests could look like:

```js
describe("TestingClass", () => {
  const mockConnectionUrl = "http://localhost:1234";

  let mockDependency: DIClass = {
      connect: () => mockConnectionUrl,
    },
    classBeingTested: TestingClass;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    classBeingTested = new TestingClass(mockDependency);
  });

  test("I'm testing a dependency without spying", () => {
    classBeingTested.connect();

    expect(classBeingTested.connection).toBe(mockConnectionUrl);
  });

  test("I'm testing a dependency with spying", () => {
    const differentConnectionUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4321";

    jest
      .spyOn(mockDependency, "connect")
      .mockReturnValue(differentConnectionUrl);

    classBeingTested.connect();

    expect(classBeingTested.connection).toBe(differentConnectionUrl);
  });
});
```

Remember, you are testing you business logic, not that your installed packages work; that's up to the packages' maintainers

Comment: Well of course, I could swicth to DI, I could migrate whole project to something like nestjs and it would make life a whole lot easier, it wouldnt even be a big problem. But that doesnt answer the question, i dont see any reason why mocking parent class should cause child to lose all methods upon construction. 

And about that `...jest.requireActual()` part ... that was just my futile attempt of fixing the problem, never wanted to test that code in the first place

Comment: Obviously every project has its own quirks and challenges, however, I don't see many reasons why you should extend a third-party class instead of passing it as an argument. This would make your code cleaner, easier to test, more modular and more maintainable. And yes, Nestjs makes the whole DI business much more efficient because they implement the Singleton pattern for you, but not using Nest shouldn't be a reason to not use DI.

Comment: Now, as a side-note, there are ways you can achieve your goal. Doing something like `jest.spyOn(DIClass.prototype, "connect").mockReturnValue(mockConnectionUrl)` will allow you to mock methods from the parent class. You should also read the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks) on mocking classes. They are pretty comprehensive so you should find a way there too :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem, did you find the solution?